# Access denied on all users except root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Been looking for an answer to this for hours now, and can't find one.

I'm trying to SSH into my Ubuntu server. I can login with no problem as root, but as soon as I try to create another user and login, I get "access denied" messages.

I'm certain that the password I'm using is correct. The user's home directory is at /home/USERNAME and has 0755 permissions.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is the shell of the other user? What command did you use to create it? What error message are you getting? Where are you sshing from?

Answer (score -1):

Not every user is allowed to login via ssh. You have to authorize the users you want to have access in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Check out [this tutorial](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/how-do-i-permit-specific-users-ssh-access) for more details.

Comment: I've checked my sshd_config file, and there doesn't appear to be anything to prevent users logging in. My sshd_config file: http://pastebin.com/ws777e7x

Comment: @VettelS if you had checked the link in my answer you would have seen that you need to add the key "AllowUsers" followed by the users you want to grant access to your conf. Alternatively you can add the users to the group sshusers as this group is allowed in your conf by the line "AllowGroups sshusers".

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the stock Ubuntu sshd config that requires modifying the sshd_config file per-user.